# Metric spaces that are homeomorphic but only one has Heine-Borel property

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I was asked to find this counterexample (for general topological spaces) but i'm pretty interested in the case that they are both metric.

My thoughts: Because Heine-Borel has an equivalence to Completeness axiom,will it  be enough to pick the real line and construct a homeomorphism with the open set $(0,1)$ which is not complete  with the inherited metric of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, this will work, though you’ll need to explain why. For instance, the set $\left(0,\frac12\right]$ is closed and bounded in $(0,1)$, but it’s not compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider $\hat{d}:=\min\{d,1\}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is easily seen to generate the same topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now take a close look on the properties of $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself on the metric given by $\hat{d}$ (the properties related to Heine-Borel).

OBS: Your idea also works fine, because $(0,1)$ is closed (*in itself*, of course) and bounded but not compact.

OBS2: How were you told to show this for general topological spaces if the Heine-borel is a statement about *bounded* sets? (there are generalizations of "bounded" to some spaces which are not metric, but I don't know about one for general topological spaces).

Comment: I can see that the open balls in the usual topology are union of balls of radius 1 at the given topology but the real line with the given topology is close and bounded,still it has no finite subcover implying it wont be compact,but the homeomorphism i crafted wont work?

Comment: @AHandsomeAlien See the edit :)

Comment: My words misled you,for that i'll restate what i meant "i could use any topological space (i.e. finite or infinite dimensional", when i was naively asked this the OP just avoided the trouble of checking how it would sound for general  topological spaces (and so did I,maybe because i wanted so hard to use completeness,untill now),sorry